# HTTP-Request - Missing response - net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, ssl, xmlhttprequest

I'am using a **RESTful API** with **CORS**. Sometimes (can't reproduce when/why it happend) a AJAX-Request is aborted by the client and no response comes up. This happends not only in chrome, also other browser are effected. I tried debugging a lot and searched a lot for a solution, but I didn't find one right now. All the requests were procceed by the server were well, only the reponse is **blocked** **by** **client**.

The following is a `chrome://net-internals/#events` based on the request which is aborted by error`net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)`. Mostly this problem comes up while using SSL, but SSL is not in use.

```
2681: URL_REQUEST
http://solid-rm-api/api/role/create
Start Time: 2016-02-23 15:55:16.152

t=97023 [st=   0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=1930]
t=97023 [st=   0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=97023 [st=   0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=1930]
--> load_flags = 34626 (BYPASS_CACHE | DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | DO_NOT_SEND_AUTH_DATA | DO_NOT_SEND_COOKIES | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
--> method = "POST"
--> priority = "LOW"
--> upload_id = "0"
--> url = "http://solid-rm-api/api/role/create"
t=97023 [st=   0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=97023 [st=   0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=97023 [st=   0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=97023 [st=   0]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=97023 [st=   0]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
--> source_dependency = 2683 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=97024 [st=   1]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
--> source_dependency = 2683 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=97024 [st=   1]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=97024 [st=   1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=97024 [st=   1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
--> POST /api/role/create HTTP/1.1
                             Host: solid-rm-api
                             Connection: keep-alive
                             Content-Length: 404
                             Pragma: no-cache
                             Cache-Control: no-cache
                             Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
                             User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
                             App-Token: ABC
                             Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
                             Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
                             Token: 123123123123123123123123
                             Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/
                             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                             Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
t=97024 [st=   1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
                         --> did_merge = true
                         --> is_chunked = false
                         --> length = 404
t=97024 [st=   1]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=97024 [st=   1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=1929]
t=97024 [st=   1]       +HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=1929]
t=98953 [st=1930]          CANCELLED
t=98953 [st=1930]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                     --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=98953 [st=1930]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=98953 [st=1930] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this after months. It has turned out that `net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)` **is allways an timeout abort state fired by the application itself**. In our case the XHR-Timeout was globally overriden by an third party library. It was set to `2000ms` by this library. In that way some of our request which took longer than 2000ms were aborted by the client. The result is `net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)`.

If you are facing the same problem. Check your codes and ensure that the timeout set in your application is configured for your needs.

Comment: Kudos to you for coming back with an update a year later. This might help me with a bug I'm having with the same error message.